# How to convert a String with coordinates to a List in dart

Tags: string, list, dart

I want to convert a string with value "[0, 0]" to a list with value [0, 0]. Somewhat like casting a string to a list.

Code:

```dart
void main(){
  String cords_string = "[0, 0]";
  List<int> cords_list = ;//i want to make this have a value of [0, 0] or whatever value cords_string has 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.decode` from `dart:convert` to get a `List<dynamic>`, and from there you can convert it to a `List<int>`. This is one way to do it:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String cords_string = "[0, 0]";
  List<int> cords_list = [...json.decode(cords_string)];
  print(cords_list);
}
```

Alternatively you could use `List<int>.from(json.decode(cords_string))` instead.